# Interpretation of mixed model with repeated measures

Tags: mixed-model, spss, repeated-measures, interpretation

I have performed the following experiment: Two genotype groups of two different ages were monitored in the presence of three drugs one after the other. So, each subject after a control period received drug A, then drug B and then drug C. I want to know what is the effect of every drug compared to control and between each of them and also check for drug*genotype*age interactions. As far as I understand, I have a mixed model with one within-subjects factor (drug) and two between-subjects factors (genotype and age). I'm using SPSS and I'm running repeated measures test (responses follow normal distribution and Levene's test of equality of error variances is not significant).

**My question is:** How many levels should be included in the within-subjects factor? Should I run one test with 4 within-subjects levels or run a separate test for each comparison between drugs with 2 levels in each test?

I think that the correct procedure would be to run one test with 4 levels, but, I am concerned about the question that such a comparison asks. The reason is, that none of the drugs are expected to work in the same way. Some are expected to show reduced response and others increased response. So, if I run such a comparison with all 4 levels I feel I'm asking if *all* of the drugs affect the two genotypes and ages in a similar way, which is different to my original question of finding differences between *each* of the drugs.

Many thanks